# How to pass javascript variable to javascript src link

Tags: javascript

How to pass javascript variable to javascript src link

I want to pass variable myoutput to replace YOUR_LABEL_HERE with variable value

My code:

```
 <script>
    var myoutput = 'Diet';
</script>
<script src="/feeds/posts/default/-/YOUR_LABEL_HERE?published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=labelthumbs" type='text/javascript'> </script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+create+script+element+dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it an `id`, which then allows you to target it like any other element, then change its `src` :

(inspect the snippet's result to see the change)

```js
const theScript = document.getElementById("changeMySrc"),
      theVariable = "something"

theScript.src = "http://somesite.com/" + theVariable + "/urlEnd"
```

```html
<script id="changeMySrc"></script>
```

The script is now `<script id="changeMySrc" src="http://somesite.com/something/urlEnd"></script>`.